# Show div when sum of three dropdown is greater than 300

Tags: javascript, html, sum, dropdown

I don't know how to figure out my problem. I have three selectors (dropdown) and when the sum of these three lists is greater than 300, there should show a div with a checkbox. It's for my form when a customer want order more than 300 products he can get something for free. 
I can get the sum of these lists in a input but the value of this input is not showing so i CAN'T  use this to show the div:

```js
//this is not working
Event.observe('total', 'keyup', function () {
     if ($$('#total]')[0].value > 299){
         $$('#show300')[0].show();
     }
     else{
         $$('#show300')[0].hide();
     }
});
```

```html
<div class="input-group-inzerat"><select name="Produkt 1" class="custom-select1" id="sum"><option selected value="0">Množstvo</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="60">60</option><option value="70">70</option><option value="80">80</option><option value="90">90</option><option value="100">100</option><option value="150">150</option><option value="200">200</option><option value="300">300</option></select></div>
<div class="input-group-inzerat"><select name="Produkt 2" class="custom-select1" id="sum"><option selected value="0">Množstvo</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="60">60</option><option value="70">70</option><option value="80">80</option><option value="90">90</option><option value="100">100</option><option value="150">150</option><option value="200">200</option><option value="300">300</option></select></div>
<div class="input-group-inzerat"><select name="Produkt 3" class="custom-select1" id="sum"><option selected value="0">Množstvo</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="60">60</option><option value="70">70</option><option value="80">80</option><option value="90">90</option><option value="100">100</option><option value="150">150</option><option value="200">200</option><option value="300">300</option></select></div>

<input type="text" name="total" id="total" style="display: block" />

<div class="form-check" id="show300" ><input name="Logo" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Ano" id="formCheck-1" style="font-size: 30px;" /><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Áno chcem využiť ponuku &quot;Logo zdarma&quot;</label></div>
```

Can somebody help me? Please :)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple `select` with same `id`. `id` need to be unique. So you can use `class`.

Create two functions one which will add event `change` to each of this select , so whenever select changes that function will trigger and in another function with every change of select get the value from each of the select element and do the summation of those values to show/hide the div

```js
const showDiv = document.getElementById('show300');
const elem = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-select1');
calculateTotal = () => {
  let total = 0;
  elem.forEach((item) => {
    total += parseInt(item.value, 10);
  });
  total > 300 ? showDiv.classList.add('show') : showDiv.classList.remove('show')
}

elem.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal)
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group-inzerat">
  <select name="Produkt 1" class="custom-select1">
    <option selected value="0">Množstvo</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="60">60</option>
    <option value="70">70</option>
    <option value="80">80</option>
    <option value="90">90</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="150">150</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="input-group-inzerat">
  <select name="Produkt 2" class="custom-select1">
    <option selected value="0">Množstvo</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="60">60</option>
    <option value="70">70</option>
    <option value="80">80</option>
    <option value="90">90</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="150">150</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="input-group-inzerat">
  <select name="Produkt 3" class="custom-select1">
    <option selected value="0">Množstvo</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="60">60</option>
    <option value="70">70</option>
    <option value="80">80</option>
    <option value="90">90</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="150">150</option>
    <option value="200">200</option>
    <option value="300">300</option>
  </select>
</div>

<input type="text" name="total" id="total" style="display: block" />

<div class="form-check hide" id="show300"><input name="Logo" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Ano" id="formCheck-1" style="font-size: 30px;" /><label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Áno chcem využiť ponuku &quot;Logo zdarma&quot;</label></div>
```